# Получение онлайна игроков SAMP сервера

Tags: c#, сеть

Есть лаунчер написанный на C# WPF. 
Нужно в label (который в лаунчере) вывести кол-во онлайн игроков на сервере SA:MP. 
Библиотек, которые могли бы помочь с этим нет. 
Как поступать в данный момент не знаю, буду рад любой подсказке, готов оплатить кофе с печеньками в качестве благодарности по итогу. 
Просьба не ругать, буду рад каждой зацепке.

Нашел вот такой скрипт... Возможно с его помощью можно что-то реализовать.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows;

namespace SAMP
{
    public class SAMP : IDisposable
    {
        Socket qSocket;
        IPAddress address;
        int _port = 0;
        string _password = null;
        string[] results = new string[50];
        int _count = 0;

        public SAMP(string addr, int port, string password, bool dns)
        {
            qSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            qSocket.SendTimeout = 5000;
            qSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
            if (dns)
            {
                try
                {
                    address = Dns.GetHostAddresses(addr)[0];
                }
                catch { }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    address = IPAddress.Parse(addr);
                }
                catch { }
            }

            _port = port;
            _password = password;
        }

        public bool Send(string command)
        {
            try
            {
                IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(address, _port);
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
                    {
                        writer.Write("SAMP".ToCharArray());
                        string[] SplitIP = address.ToString().Split('.');
                        writer.Write(Convert.ToByte(SplitIP[0]));
                        writer.Write(Convert.ToByte(SplitIP[1]));
                        writer.Write(Convert.ToByte(SplitIP[2]));
                        writer.Write(Convert.ToByte(SplitIP[3]));
                        writer.Write((ushort)_port);
                        writer.Write('x');
                        writer.Write((ushort)_password.Length);
                        writer.Write(_password.ToCharArray());
                        writer.Write((ushort)command.Length);
                        writer.Write(command.ToCharArray());
                    }
                    if (qSocket.SendTo(stream.ToArray(), endpoint) > 0) return true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public int Receive()
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < results.GetLength(0); i++) results.SetValue(null, i);
                _count = 0;
                EndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(address, _port);
                byte[] rBuffer = new byte[500];
                int count = qSocket.ReceiveFrom(rBuffer, ref endpoint);
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(rBuffer))
                {
                    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
                    {
                        if (stream.Length <= 11) return _count;
                        reader.ReadBytes(11);
                        short len;
                        try
                        {
                            while ((len = reader.ReadInt16()) != 0) results[_count++] = new string(reader.ReadChars((int)len));
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            return _count;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return _count;
            }
            return _count;
        }

        public string[] Store(int count = -1)
        {
            string[] rString = new string[count != -1 ? count : _count];
            for (int i = 0; (i < count || count == -1) && i < _count; i++) rString[i] = results[i];
            _count = 0;
            return rString;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            try
            {
                qSocket.Dispose();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }

    public class Query : IDisposable
    {
        Socket qSocket;
        IPAddress address;
        int _port = 0;
        string[] results;
        int _count = 0;
        DateTime[] timestamp = new DateTime[2];

        public string passworded;
        public string players;
        public string max_players;
        public string hostname;
        public string gamemode;
        public string mapname;

        public enum PaketOpcode
        {
            Info = 'i',
            Rules = 'r',
            ClientList = 'c',
            DetailedClientList = 'd',
            Ping = 'p'
        }

        public Query(string addr, int port, bool dns)
        {
            qSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

            qSocket.SendTimeout = 5000;
            qSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
            if (dns)
            {
                try
                {
                    address = Dns.GetHostAddresses(addr)[0];
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("An error has occured in SAMP API!\n\n" + e.ToString());
                    Environment.Exit(2);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    address = IPAddress.Parse(addr);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
            _port = port;
        }

        public bool Send(char opcode, string sign = "1337")
        {
            try
            {
                EndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(address, _port);
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
                    {
                        writer.Write("SAMP".ToCharArray());
                        string[] SplitIP = address.ToString().Split('.');
                        writer.Write(Convert.ToByte(SplitIP[0]));
                        writer.Write(Convert.ToByte(SplitIP[1]));
                        writer.Write(Convert.ToByte(SplitIP[2]));
                        writer.Write(Convert.ToByte(SplitIP[3]));
                        writer.Write((ushort)_port);
                        writer.Write(opcode);
                        if (opcode == 'p') writer.Write(sign.ToCharArray());
                        timestamp[0] = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                    if (qSocket.SendTo(stream.ToArray(), endpoint) > 0) return true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public int Receive()
        {
            try
            {
                _count = 0;
                EndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(address, _port);
                byte[] rBuffer = new byte[500];
                qSocket.ReceiveFrom(rBuffer, ref endpoint);
                timestamp[1] = DateTime.Now;
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(rBuffer))
                {
                    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
                    {
                        if (stream.Length <= 10) return _count;
                        reader.ReadBytes(10);
                        switch (reader.ReadChar())
                        {
                            case 'i':
                                {
                                    results = new string[6];
                                    passworded = reader.ReadByte().ToString();
                                    //results[_count++] = reader.ReadByte().ToString(); // either 0 or 1, depending whether if the password has been set.
                                    players = reader.ReadInt16().ToString();
                                    //results[_count++] = reader.ReadInt16().ToString(); // current amount of players online on the server
                                    max_players = reader.ReadInt16().ToString();
                                    //results[_count++] = reader.ReadInt16().ToString(); // maximum amount of players that can join the server
                                    hostname = new string(reader.ReadChars(reader.ReadInt32()));
                                    //results[_count++] = new string(reader.ReadChars(reader.ReadInt32())); // hostname
                                    gamemode = new string(reader.ReadChars(reader.ReadInt32()));
                                    //results[_count++] = new string(reader.ReadChars(reader.ReadInt32())); // gamemode
                                    mapname = new string(reader.ReadChars(reader.ReadInt32()));
                                    //results[_count++] = new string(reader.ReadChars(reader.ReadInt32())); // mapname
                                    return 6;
                                }

                            case 'r':
                                {
                                    int rulecount = reader.ReadInt16();
                                    results = new string[rulecount * 2];
                                    for (int i = 0; i < rulecount; i++)
                                    {
                                        results[_count++] = new string(reader.ReadChars(reader.ReadByte())); // rule name (key)
                                        results[_count++] = new string(reader.ReadChars(reader.ReadByte())); // rule value (value)
                                    }
                                    return _count;
                                }

                            case 'c':
                                {
                                    int playercount = reader.ReadInt16();
                                    results = new string[playercount * 2];
                                    for (int i = 0; i < playercount; i++)
                                    {
                                        results[_count++] = new string(reader.ReadChars(reader.ReadByte())); // nickname
                                        results[_count++] = reader.ReadInt32().ToString(); // score
                                    }
                                    return _count;
                                }

                            case 'd':
                                {
                                    int playercount = reader.ReadInt16();
                                    results = new string[playercount * 4];
                                    for (int i = 0; i < playercount; i++)
                                    {
                                        results[_count++] = reader.ReadByte().ToString(); //playerid
                                        results[_count++] = new string(reader.ReadChars(reader.ReadByte())); //nick
                                        results[_count++] = reader.ReadInt32().ToString(); //score
                                        results[_count++] = reader.ReadInt32().ToString(); //ping
                                    }
                                    return _count;
                                }

                            case 'p':
                                {
                                    results = new string[1];
                                    results[_count++] = timestamp[1].Subtract(timestamp[0]).Milliseconds.ToString(); // time difference
                                    results[_count++] = new string(reader.ReadChars(4)); // paket signature
                                    return _count;
                                }

                            default: return _count;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return _count;
            }
        }

        public string[] Store(int count)
        {
            string[] rString = new string[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count && i < _count; i++) rString[i] = results[i];
            _count = 0;
            return rString;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            try
            {
                qSocket.Dispose();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Еще реализация на PHP:

```
<?php
/**
 * This file is part of GameQ.
 *
 * GameQ is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * GameQ is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
 * along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */
namespace GameQ\Protocols;

use GameQ\Exception\Protocol as Exception;
use GameQ\Result;
use GameQ\Server;

/**
 * Grand Theft Auto Network Protocol Class
 * https://stats.gtanet.work/
 *
 * Result from this call should be a header + JSON response
 *
 * References:
 * - https://master.gtanet.work/apiservers
 *
 * @author Austin Bischoff <austin@codebeard.com>
 */
class Gtan extends Http
{
    /**
     * Packets to send
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $packets = [
        //self::PACKET_STATUS => "GET /apiservers HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: master.gtanet.work\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n",
        self::PACKET_STATUS => "GET /gtan/api.php?ip=%s&raw HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: multiplayerhosting.info\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n",
    ];

    /**
     * Http protocol is SSL
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $transport = self::TRANSPORT_SSL;

    /**
     * The protocol being used
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $protocol = 'gtan';

    /**
     * String name of this protocol class
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'gtan';

    /**
     * Longer string name of this protocol class
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name_long = "Grand Theft Auto Network";

    /**
     * Holds the real ip so we can overwrite it back
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $realIp = null;

    protected $realPortQuery = null;

    /**
     * Normalize some items
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $normalize = [
        // General
        'general' => [
            // target       => source
            'dedicated'  => 'dedicated',
            'hostname'   => 'hostname',
            'mapname'    => 'map',
            'mod'        => 'mod',
            'maxplayers' => 'maxplayers',
            'numplayers' => 'numplayers',
            'password'   => 'password',
        ],
    ];

    public function beforeSend(Server $server)
    {
        // Loop over the packets and update them
        foreach ($this->packets as $packetType => $packet) {
            // Fill out the packet with the server info
            $this->packets[$packetType] = sprintf($packet, $server->ip . ':' . $server->port_query);
        }

        $this->realIp = $server->ip;
        $this->realPortQuery = $server->port_query;

        // Override the existing settings
        //$server->ip = 'master.gtanet.work';
        $server->ip = 'multiplayerhosting.info';
        $server->port_query = 443;
    }

    /**
     * Process the response
     *
     * @return array
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function processResponse()
    {
        // No response, assume offline
        if (empty($this->packets_response)) {
            return [
                'gq_address'    => $this->realIp,
                'gq_port_query' => $this->realPortQuery,
            ];
        }

        // Implode and rip out the JSON
        preg_match('/\{(.*)\}/ms', implode('', $this->packets_response), $matches);

        // Return should be JSON, let's validate
        if (!isset($matches[0]) || ($json = json_decode($matches[0])) === null) {
            throw new Exception("JSON response from Gtan protocol is invalid.");
        }

        $result = new Result();

        // Server is always dedicated
        $result->add('dedicated', 1);

        $result->add('gq_address', $this->realIp);
        $result->add('gq_port_query', $this->realPortQuery);

        // Add server items
        $result->add('hostname', $json->ServerName);
        $result->add('serverversion', $json->ServerVersion);
        $result->add('map', ((!empty($json->Map)) ? $json->Map : 'Los Santos/Blaine Country'));
        $result->add('mod', $json->Gamemode);
        $result->add('password', (int)$json->Passworded);
        $result->add('numplayers', $json->CurrentPlayers);
        $result->add('maxplayers', $json->MaxPlayers);

        return $result->fetch();
    }
}
```

Comment: А как вы себе представляете помощь в этом вопросе? Вот давайте гипотетически, я спрошу у вас, "Нужно, чтоб у меня на столе лежал документ, в котором будет написано сколько сотрудников". Ваши действия? Как вы мне в этом поможете? Вы не знаете, что за фирма, не знаете, как в ней все устроено, не знаете, кто ответственный за эти данные, не знаете вообще нечего. Ну так и какая будет польза от вас мне? Также и тут, мы совершенно не знаем что за сервер, как он работает, есть ли у него возможность получения этих данных, мы знаем только, что есть WPF проект, в котором должно быть число из игры, все.

Comment: Можно на [гитхабе](https://github.com/kfirprods/SAMP-API) покопаться.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я в такой же ситуации, знаю сам ровно столько, сколько передал, и прошу помочь людей знающих о этой теме.

Comment: `Библиотек, которые могли бы помочь с этим нет.` как вы это поняли? Если проблема есть не только у вас, значит ее уже кто-то решил.

Comment: @aepot большинство разработок лаунчеров для этих проектов делают на Devil Studio, упаси ассемблер называть это в слух. А здесь именно на C# нужно было.

Comment: Ну хорошо, а как вы тогда себе представляете решение данной задачи? Если сервер не отдает публично этих данных, то вы вряд-ли выведите такое значение. Если сервер ваш, то пишите под него не знаю, плагин, который будет в публичный доступ отдавать эти данные. Вот например SO, он сохраняет удаленные ответы, вопросы, комментарии. Как вы эти данные получите, без доступа к ним?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ дополнил кодом в описании, нашел на github что-то похожее для работы с сервером

Comment: Во, зацепка есть.

Comment: Так а сервер-то ваш?

Comment: @aepot ещё samp работает на сети raknet, может тоже поможет

Comment: @EvgeniyZ нет, лаунчер способствует подключению к нужному  игроку  серверу из доступных в нём.

Comment: Ну тогда у вас нету прав к этой информации, как вы хотите вывести? Даже ваш код вон выше требует пароль.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а пароль к чему конкретно?

Comment: @aepot на PHP реализацию нашел, ее можно как-то реализовать под C#?

Comment: Ок, поизучал я вопрос. SAMP работает на сокетах, UDP соединение. Чтож вы не напомнили, что сам клиент пишет сколько человек на сервере и его данные... Вот [короче](https://github.com/zeelorenc/SA-MP-Server-Query-Class/blob/master/SampQueryApi.cs), если нечего не изменилось с 13-го года, то может и сработает. Если-же нет, то извиняйте, отлавливайте тогда пакеты, который делает клиент на сервер и их эмулируйте. А вообще, на сколько я помню, это обычно выводили плагинами на всякие сайты и прочее, то есть, на сервере был плагин, который формировал данные для удобного вывода.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ благодарю!)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ сделал вывод, сработало. Теперь вопрос в выводе кол-ва в переменную, а не в словарь. Тут идет запись кол-ва игроков на сервере:
`dData.Add("players", Convert.ToString(read.ReadInt16()));`

Я пытался сделать так: 
`Console.WriteLine(api.PLAYERSONLINE); // PLAYERSONLINE - int переменная`

Но вместо цифр - пустая строка и ничего не происходит.
Вот таким путем выводит всю инфу:
`foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in api.read(true))
                Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key}: {kvp.Value}");`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ уточню — "тут" - это в [SampQueryApi.cs](https://github.com/zeelorenc/SA-MP-Server-Query-Class/blob/master/SampQueryApi.cs)
Паблик `public Dictionary<string, string> read(bool flushdata = true)`

Comment: Ну вы что, не знаете, как брать из словаря данные? `var users = api.read()["players"];`...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ благодарен, искренне.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sampQuery = new SampQuery("127.0.0.1", 7777);
SampServerInfoData data = sampQuery.GetServerInfo();
label.Text = $"Online {data.Players}/{data.MaxPlayers}";
```

Больше информации вот тут https://www.blast.hk/threads/70372/

Скачать скрипт: [GitHub](https://github.com/justmavi/sampquery)